# Get all tracking numbers from DHL done by my company

Tags: python, api, dhl

I need to get the DHL tracking details of all orders done by my company.My company is an e-commerce company who ships more than 200-500 orders per day via DHL.
Our requirement is to get the tracking details of those orders using DHL API.I have searched in google and in community and done the below steps.

1) created an developer account at DHL developer portal https://developer.dhl

2) Created an application and got consumer key and secret.

3) I was only able to add 3 API's in my application and other API's are showing In-Progress.

4)Using the below **Python code** for testing purpose.

**So i want to know how can i get all the order tracking numbers done by my company, In the developer portal there is no link or connection of my company details mentioned.So how i get those?**

I do have a business portal at DHL side, So can anyone help me to identify or suggest what i need to do for getting the tracking details of the orders done by my company.

```
    import requests
    import json
    import http.client
    import urllib.parse

    params = urllib.parse.urlencode({
        'trackingNumber': '00340********659247',
        'service': 'express'
    })

    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'DHL-API-Key': 'hyBYOzGX*****sLeE4RUAhZkwzuvL'
              }
    payload = {
        'trackingNumber': '003404******659247',
        'service': 'express'
             }

    url = 'https://api.dhl.com/dgff/transportation/shipment-tracking?housebill=00340434289671659247'
    myResponse = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers)

    print(myResponse.content)
    print (myResponse.status_code)
```

Comment: This sounds like a great question to ask the DHL API team, there's probably a way to contact them on the site

Answer (score 0):

So if what you have so far is working, you can simply loop through all the numbers. of course this means you'll have to compile them into a list somehow...

```
import requests
import json
tracknums=[1,2,3,4,5,6.....] #just dummy numbers of course...

for num in tracknums:
    headers = {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'DHL-API-Key': 'hyBYOzGX*****sLeE4RUAhZkwzuvL'
              }
    payload = {
        'trackingNumber': num,
        'service': 'express'
             }

    url = 'https://api.dhl.com/dgff/transportation/shipment-tracking?housebill=00340434289671659247'
    myResponse = requests.get(url, params=payload, headers=headers)


    if myResponse.status_code==200:
        #do some stuff....
```

Comment: I need to get the list of tracking numbers for the orders done by my company, I cannot hardcode the tracking numbers as mentioned above.  Can you please help me  how to get the tracking number of the orders done by my company using DHL API? Is there anything i need to do or any settings or different API?

Comment: @Linu the api doesn't return the tracking numbers, correct? You need those as an input to get the status?

Comment: Actually the exact requirement is to get the tracking numbers.My company is sending upto 500 shipments to DHL and we want to get the list of tracking numbers of those as soon as the numbers are generated on the DHL side.Is it possible?

Comment: @Linu It sounds like something that's possible, but I'm not familiar with the DHL API, is there documentation describing how to use it to get tracking numbers?

Comment: I have contacted the DHL developer portal and they informed me, as of now that is not possible to get all tracking numbers of a particular company, but we ca pass the tracking number to their API and get the status of shipments.This is the link https://developer.dhl/documentation